# MIPS - Runtime exception at 0x004001e8: fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x10010001

Tags: mips

I am trying to implement `puts` in MIPS. I have a procedure `putchar` which prints a char to the screen :

```
    .text
putchar:
    lui $t0, 0xffff     # base address of memory map
XReady:
    lw $t1, 8($t0)      #read from transmitter control register
    andi $t1, $t1, 0x1  # extract ready bit
    beqz $t1, XReady       # if 1, store char ; else, loop
    sw $a0, 12($t0)     # send character to display
    jr $ra                 # return to place in program before function call
```

In my main subroutine, I set $a0 to the string I want to print and then I call `puts` :

```
la $a0, array       # defined in .data as -- array: .space 2000 --
gal puts
```

I get an error fetch address not aligned on word boundary on line 242 of `puts` (marked with a *)

```
    .text
puts:
    addi $sp, $sp, -24  # make room for 6 registers
    sw $ra, 20($sp)     # save $ra on the stack
    sw $s0, 16($sp)     # save $s0 on the stack
    sw, $s1, 12($sp)    # save $s1 on the stack
    sw, $s2, 8($sp)     # save $s2 on the stack
    sw, $s3, 4($sp)     # save $s3 on the stack
    sw, $s4, 0($sp)     # save $s4 on the stack

    move $s0, $a0       # copy parameter $a0 into $s0
    move $s1, $a1       # copy parameter $a0 into $s1
    move $s2, $a2       # copy parameter $a0 into $s2
    move $s3, $a3       # copy parameter $a0 into $s3
    move $s4, $zero     # s4 is a character counter. $s4 = 0
getsLoop:
    addi $t0, $zero, 0x00   # Put NULL ascii character inside $t0
    sll $t1, $s4, 2     # create buffer storing address ($t1 = $s1 * 4)
    add $t2, $s0, $t1   # register #t2 now holds buffer address
*   lw $t3, ($s0)       # load char into #t3
    beq $t3, $t0, exitPuts  # exit puts if the current character is the NULL character

    move $a0, $t3       # put the character to print inside $a0, accessible by putchar
    jal putchar     # print char using putchar
    addi $s0, $s0, 1    # character count += 1
    j getsLoop      # Loop to print next character
exitPuts:
    lw $s4, 0($sp)      # restore stack
    lw $s3, 4($sp)      # -
    lw $s2, 8($sp)      # -
    lw $s1, 12($sp)     # -
    lw $s0, 16($sp)     # -
    lw $ra, 20($sp)     # -
    addi $sp, $sp, 20   # pop from stack
    jr $ra          # return
```

I don't why I'm getting this error... Isn't `$s0` the address of `array` defined in main?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `lw` you load an entire *word* (4 bytes, not to be confused with words in natural languages), and that word has to be aligned on a word boundary (the two least significant bits of the address have to be 0).

ASCII characters are typically stored using one byte per character, so you should use the `lbu` instruction to load them instead of `lw`.

Comment: Thank you, your modification worked.  I'm curious though... My `getchar` is reading a word in memory and I address the array word by word. Are you telling me that even if I used `sw` inside `getchar`, it saved the ASCII as one byte?

Comment: Since I haven't seen that code I don't know. Maybe it groups 4 character into a register and then stores them using `sw`.